# Metricbeat sends process metrics even if it is disabled

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, metricbeat

i have the following config for metricbeat:

```
metricbeat.config.modules:
 path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
 reload.enabled: false

metricbeat_modules:
 - module: system
   metricsets:
    - cpu
    - load
    - memory
    - network
    - diskio
  enabled: true
  period: 10s
  tags: ['os']
  cpu.metrics: ['percentages']
  core.metrics: ['percentages']

setup.template:
  name: {{ metricbeat_index }}
  pattern: {{ metricbeat_index }}-*
  settings:
    index:
      number_of_shards: 1
      codec: best_compression

tags: [{{ metricbeat_tags | join(', ') }}]

fields:
  env: {{ metricbeat_env }}

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: {{ metricbeat_output_es_hosts | to_json }}
  index: "{{ metricbeat_index }}-%{+yyyy-MM-dd}"

setup.dashboards.directory: /usr/share/metricbeat/kibana

setup.kibana:
  host: {{ metricbeat_kibana_url }}

processors: 
- drop_fields:
    fields: ["beat.name","beat.hostname"]

processors:
- add_host_metadata:
    netinfo.enabled: false

processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

it worked as expected as i had the metricsets `process` and `process_summary` enabled. since i removed them it seems still to harvest those metrics. i restarted, stopped/started metricbeat again but it still has no effect. 
Thanks for ideas as i cannot see any reason why this should happen this way :/

Comment: Which version of metricbeats are you running ? Do you have any other config files in modules.d directory ? Can you post your full metricbeat.yml ?

Comment: I edited the config. im running metricbeat v 6.4.2 on aws ec2. the only processor which takes effect is the cloud_meta_data. the other ones are ignored as well

Comment: Does your logs show anything helpful ?

Comment: Unfortunately they look as intended. I fixed the processors issue, i thought i could specify multiple processors keys but it only works if i stack them under one key... i guess the process issue rises from one of the modules as they might store infos under that key otherwise i cannot explain this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I digged a bit more into you issue.
You sepcify a module config folder with this part of your config:

```
metricbeat.config.modules:
 path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
 reload.enabled: false
```

If you run look info that folder I'm sure you'll find this:

```
aerospike.yml.disabled
apache.yml.disabled
ceph.yml.disabled
couchbase.yml.disabled
docker.yml.disabled
dropwizard.yml.disabled
elasticsearch.yml.disabled
envoyproxy.yml.disabled
etcd.yml.disabled
golang.yml.disabled
graphite.yml.disabled
haproxy.yml.disabled
http.yml.disabled
jolokia.yml.disabled
kafka.yml.disabled
kibana.yml.disabled
kubernetes.yml.disabled
kvm.yml.disabled
logstash.yml.disabled
memcached.yml.disabled
mongodb.yml.disabled
munin.yml.disabled
mysql.yml.disabled
nginx.yml.disabled
php_fpm.yml.disabled
postgresql.yml.disabled
prometheus.yml.disabled
rabbitmq.yml.disabled
redis.yml.disabled
system.yml
traefik.yml.disabled
uwsgi.yml.disabled
vsphere.yml.disabled
windows.yml.disabled
zookeeper.yml.disabled
```

See that `system.yml` file ?
This is the configuration that is loaded.
So you can remove process from this configuration file or not use `metricbeat.config.modules.path`

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Shoudln't you have `metricbeat.modules` instead of `metricbeat_modules` ?